# make left sidebar stay in position during scrolling in Foundation

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation

I would like to make my left sidebar stay in place when I scroll up and down. I only like the content scroll. The content is the one with the h4 Task 1 Content and is displayed on the right side.

```
<div class="container page">
  <div ng-include="'app/components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
  <div class="row page">

    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns sidebar">
      <div class="row">

        <a class="medium-6 columns menu-item button">
          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page-add></i>
            <p>Task 1</p>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="medium-6 columns menu-item button">
          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page-edit"></i>
            <p>Task 2</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 large-8 columns content">
      <h4>Task 1 Content</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      <div class="form-group large-6">
        <p><input type="text" ng-model="someModel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter string"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assign it a fixed position.

Comment: yup. Was hoping there was a Foundation class rather than overriding their scss again with our own values

Comment: I'm pretty sure their class `fixed` does that :)

Comment: I used it and if affected the whole layout of my project

Comment: Then see what it is their CSS causing it. I would try with your own class (wouldn't override anything if it was a unique class).

Comment: Someone from zurb replied to my comment and gave an example. I will try it later once I get a chance. I'll share the code too.